# Tesseract not giving the correct output after processing CAPTCHA

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, captcha, python-tesseract

[image: my_image]

I have been trying to get the output of this image as text using tesseract. I have tried many ways but unable to do it. I think it has to do with that line that is cutting the letters but you might still want to try. I am a newbie and think you experts can do it.

This is my code:

```py
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv
import time
import cv2
import pytesseract
import imutils
from pytesseract import Output

img = cv2.imread('canvas.png')
image = imutils.resize(img, width=700)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)
```

I appreciate your help.

Output i got is: SHY AR ( it is incorrect, it should be 3HYXK)

Comment: my output was SHY AR.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install tesseract as a library and import it.
For example:

```
from pytesseract import Output

img = cv2.imread('canvas.jpg')
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
print(d.keys())
```

Comment: hi, this doesnt work.